# Clearing TextFields in SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

How can I clear the content of the fields of the SharedPreferences `onCreate` of the activity without affecting the old SharedPreferences? The SharedPreferences are not saved unless the user presses "addUser"; I want him to be able to cancel and go back before editing the preferences.

So this means that the name field must be empty in the beginning, but if I retrieve its value it must hold some old SharedPreferences; if I press "addUser", then the sharedpreference will change to the new values.

Here is my code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.createprofile);
    SharedPreferences customSharedPreference = getSharedPreferences(
            "myCustomSharedPrefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);



    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.namefield);
    // When i take off this line the name is cleared but if i do it to other fields it crashes.
    name.setText(customSharedPreference.getString("namepref", ""));

    age = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.agefield);


    age.setText(customSharedPreference.getString("agepref", ""));

    genderradiogroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup2);
    rb_male = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.maleradiobutton);
    rb_female = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.femaleradiobutton);
    genderradiogroup.check(customSharedPreference.getInt("genderprefs",
            rb_male.getId()));
   genderradiogroup.check(customSharedPreference.getInt("genderprefs",
          rb_male.getId()));


    weight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.weightfield);
    weight.setText(customSharedPreference.getString("weightpref", ""));

    height = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.heightfield);
    height.setText(customSharedPreference.getString("heightpref", ""));

    levelofactivity = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup3);
    rb_light = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.lightradiobutton);
    rb_moderate = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.moderateradiobutton);
    rb_heavy = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.heavyradiobutton);
   levelofactivity.check(customSharedPreference.getInt("levelpref",
           rb_light.getId()));



        Age = Integer.parseInt(age.getText().toString());
        Weight = Integer.parseInt(weight.getText().toString());
        Height = Integer.parseInt(height.getText().toString());


    Button addUser = (Button) findViewById(R.id.checkcreateprofilebutton);

    addUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            savePreferences();


            float calnumber = calculateCalories(Age, Weight, Height);
            String lala = String.valueOf(calnumber);
            Toast.makeText(ProfilePreferenceActivity.this, lala,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            usertable.open();
            long id = usertable.createUser(name.getText().toString(), age
                    .getText().toString(), gender, weight.getText()
                    .toString(), height.getText().toString(), level,
                    calnumber);

            Toast.makeText(ProfilePreferenceActivity.this,
                    "user added with" + level + gender, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();

            usertable.close();

            Intent Filling = new Intent();
            Filling.setClass(ProfilePreferenceActivity.this,
                    FillingActivity.class);
            startActivity(Filling);

        }
    });

}

private void savePreferences() {

    SharedPreferences customSharedPreference = getSharedPreferences(
            "myCustomSharedPrefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = customSharedPreference.edit();
    editor.putString("namepref", name.getText().toString());
    editor.putString("agepref", age.getText().toString());
    editor.putInt("genderprefs", genderradiogroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
    editor.putString("heightpref", height.getText().toString());
    editor.putString("weightpref", weight.getText().toString());
    editor.putInt("levelpref", levelofactivity.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
    editor.putFloat("calpref", calnum);
    editor.commit();
    finish();

}

public float calculateCalories(int age, int weight, int height) {

    if (rb_male.isChecked()) {

        gender = "male";

        bmr = 66.5f + (13.75f * weight) + (5.003f * height)
                - (6.755f * age);

        if (rb_light.isChecked()) {
            level = "light";
            calnum = bmr * 1.375f;
        }
        if (rb_moderate.isChecked()) {
            level = "moderate";
            calnum = bmr * 1.55f;
        }
        if (rb_heavy.isChecked()) {
            level = "heavy";
            calnum = bmr * 1.725f;
        }

    } else if (rb_female.isChecked()) {

        gender = "female";

        bmr = 665 + (9.563f * weight) + (1.850f * height) - (4.676f * age);

        if (rb_light.isChecked()) {
            level = "light";
            calnum = bmr * 1.375f;
        }
        if (rb_moderate.isChecked()) {
            level = "moderate";
            calnum = bmr * 1.55f;
        }
        if (rb_heavy.isChecked()) {
            level = "heavy";
            calnum = bmr * 1.725f;
        }

    }
    return calnum;

}}
```

Comment: I'm not completely following what you're wanting to do. Are you wanting to not display the current preference data when changing this data?

Comment: I want the user to see nothing on those fields ( even thought they contain shareddata that has been previously inserted in) when he comes to this contentview. So if he clicks AddUser the previous values change, if he just cancels the previous shareddata is still there.